# Run smartctl on all disks of a server

Tags: shell-script, logs, hard-disk, raid, smartctl

My question is a quite simple , I want to run the command `smartctl -i -A` on all disks that the server have.
Think that I've too much server with different number of disks and RAID Controllers, then I need to scan all drivers for a diagnosis.
I'm thinking of running `smartctl --scan | awk '{print $1}' >> test.log`, so if I open the test.log I'll have all the drives information in it.
After this I need to run some if or do constructions to scan with `smartctl` all drivers.
I don't know if this is the best way to do this, since I need to identify the RAID Controller too.
Am heading in the right direction?

### Edit:

I'm used to use these commands to troubleshoot:

#### Without RAID Controller

```
for i in {c..d}; do
    echo "Disk sd$i" $SN $MD
    smartctl -i -A /dev/sd$i |grep -E "^  "5"|^"197"|^"198"|"FAILING_NOW"|"SERIAL""
done
```

#### PERC Controller

```
for i in {0..12}; do
    echo "$i" $SN $MD
    smartctl -i -A -T permissive /dev/sda -d megaraid,$i |grep -E "^  "5"|^"197"|^"198"|"FAILING_NOW"|"SERIAL""
done
/usr/sbin/megastatus –physical
/usr/sbin/megastatus --logical
```

#### 3ware Controller

```
for i in {0..10}; do
    echo "Disk $i" $SN $MD
    smartctl -i -A /dev/twa0 -d 3ware,$i |grep -E "^  "5"|^"197"|^"198"|"FAILING_NOW"|"SERIAL""
done
```

#### SmartArray & Megaraid Controler:

```
smartctl –a –d cciss,0 /dev/cciss/c0d0
/opt/3ware/9500/tw_cli show
cd /tmp
```

#### DD (Rewrite disk block (DESTROY DATA)):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/HD* bs=4M
HD*: sda, sdb…
```

#### Burning (Stress test (DESTROY DATA)):

```
/opt/systems/bin/vs-burnin --destructive --time=<hours> /tmp/burninlog.txt
```

#### Dmesg&kernerrors:

```
tail /var/log/kernerrors
dmesg |grep –i –E “”ata”|”fault”|”error”
```

So what I'm trying to do is automate these commands.
I want that the script verify all disks that the host have and run the appropriate `smartctl` command for the case.
Something like a menu with some options that let me choose if I want to run a `smartctl` or some destructive command, if I choose to run `smartctl`
the script will scan all disks and runs the command according to the host configuration ( with / without RAID controller),
and if I choose to run a destructive command, the script will ask me to put the disk number that I want to do this.

---

### Edit 2:

I resolved my problem with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Troubleshoot.sh
# A more elaborate version of Troubleshoot.sh.

SUCCESS=0
E_DB=99    # Error code for missing entry.

declare -A address
#       -A option declares associative array.



if [ -f Troubleshoot.log ]
then
    rm Troubleshoot.log
fi

if [ -f HDs.log ]
then
    rm HDs.log
fi

smartctl --scan | awk '{print $1}' >> HDs.log
lspci | grep -i raid >> HDs.log

getArray ()
{
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
        array[i]=$line # Put it into the array
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}

getArray "HDs.log"


for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [[ $e =~ /dev/sd* || $e =~ /dev/hd* ]]
        then
            echo "smartctl -i -A $e" >> Troubleshoot.log
            smartctl -i -A $e >> Troubleshoot.log # Run smartctl into all disks that the host have
    fi
done
exit $?   # In this case, exit code = 99, since that is function return.
```

I don't know if this solution is the right or the best one, but works for me!
Appreciate all help!!

Comment: Welcome on this site, your question is good, but to ask a question with a maximum chance of succes, you should describe precisely your goal, what you've tried so far, describe your problem if there's one and then ask your question. By applying this simple advise you could get much better answer.

Comment: And please give info on the system you are using as well. Otherwise  **[serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions)** might also be a place to ask this kind of question (**but do not ask the same question on both places!**)

Comment: @Kiwy: I put some other information, see if it's good now :)

Comment: @Ouki: I can't put to much details because of some policies of the company, all I can do is put the information that I've wrote on Edit.

Comment: @ZeroNegative what you want basically is that someone develop a script for you. and you're very unlikely to find someone who will accomplish such a task on U&L or on any other Stack Exchange web site but your question is much more complete yes.  Also take into account that I've edited 2 time your question please, try to analyse what I made so you can format correctly you question and answers next time ;-)

Comment: @Kiwi sure, I'll! Well, I just need that someone give me some way to start this, I had thought of run smartctl --scan | awk '{print $1}' >> test.log to write a log with the disks path and want to do something to catch this path and put on the command, something like this: test.log have 2 lines, /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, then the script will pick this two paths and run smartctl -i -A /dev/sda && smartctl -i -A /dev/sdb. Am I looking for help in the wrong place? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

> So what I'm trying to do is automate these commands.

This already exist and manifests in `smartd`.

You normally need to configure your desired behaviour in
`/etc/smartd.conf`

Example:

```
# DEVICESCAN: tells smartd to scan for all ATA and SCSI devices
# Alternative setting to report more useful raw temperature in syslog.
DEVICESCAN -I 194 -I 231 -I 9
```

You can alternatively put your disks explicitly like

```
/dev/sdc -d 3ware,0 -a -s L/../../7/01
```

If `smartd` discover an error, you'll get an email:

```
/dev/hdc -a -I 194 -W 4,45,55 -R 5 -m admin@example.com
```

There are also a number of other options and switches, you'll need to
read the manpage of `smartd.conf`.

Comment: but how can I inspect SMART data for all volumes *now*?

Answer (score 0):

@xeruf. I run into this question in my own work from time to time and I keep having to redo my work lol. Just so me and other people can find a basic smart output command I run this:

```
for i in $(ls /dev/sd?); do
    echo "$i"
    sudo smartctl -a $i
done
```

Comment: The construct `for i in $(ls /dev/sd?)` should be simply written as `for i in /dev/sd?`